# edismax parser and default mm

Tags: lucene, solr4, edismax

I am planning to use the eDismax query parser in SOLR to give boost to documents that have a phrase in their fields present. Now there is  a mm parameter in the edismax parser query , since the query typed by the user could be of any length (i.e. >=1) I would like to set the mm value to 1 . I have the following questions regarding this parameter.

1. Is it set to 1 by default ?
2. In my schema.xml the defaultOperator is set to "AND" should I set it to "OR" inorder for the edismax parser to be effective with a mm of 1?

Answer (score 0):

> From Solr4.0 The default value of mm is dictated by the q.op param (q.op=AND => mm=100%; q.op=OR => mm=0%). Keep in mind the default operator is effected by your schema.xml  entry. In older versions of Solr the default value of 'mm' is 100% (all clauses must match).

So, if you have AND as default operator, mm by default will be equal to number of clauses.